# How can I keep this menu?

Tags: 18.04, menu, gnome-shell, accessibility

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, when I set the scaling factor to 1.25 in the GNOME tweak tool, this menu shows up in the top panel, but It hides when I set the scaling factor to 1.00.

[image]

This menu is very convenient to access some settings, can I keep it in the top panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y always-show-universal-access-status true
```

This should make the accessibility icon always visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works, can I ask how do you learn these stuff?

Comment: @Ives It's just getting used to stuffs over time. In particular you can install the GUI application `dconf-editor` to get a good idea about `gsettings`/`dconf` keys and schemas.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can use **settings**

1. open **settings**
2. on the left click on **universal access**
3. click on the slide **Always Show Universal Access Menu**

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work on my PC.

Comment: what doesn't work? Can you open the settings menu?

Comment: Thanks, it works, I misread your post. I didn't know what does `Always Show Universal Access Menu` mean.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it points to the place where the setting is exposed to the general user. It is therefore the best and safest approach. In addition, it does not require installing software (dconf-editor) that is not installed by default.